# Octobercms: How can I make a repeater field jsonable because I am creating this repeater field into a different plugin

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

How can I make a repeater field **jsonable** because I am creating this repeater field into a different plugin and I have created my own plugin.
for example: I want to add a repeater field in **rainlab.user** plugin model but I want to do this by my own plugin so updates on **rainlab.user** plugin won't affect my work.
Thanks

Comment: can you share more details , means what is causing problem and if possible can you share code for better understanding

Comment: it's okay Hardik. i got the help from the other guy.
thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about [Extending Plugins](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending).

1) First register the events in your custom `plugin.php` - [Example](https://github.com/gergo85/oc-user-plus/blob/master/Plugin.php#L35)

2) Add the related fields to your migration file - [Example](https://github.com/gergo85/oc-user-plus/blob/master/updates/add_new_fields_to_users_table.php) - Make sure the field type is set to `json` or `text` : `$table->json('field_name')->nullable();`

Let's say you want to add a `Dogs` repeater field to the User Model ;

```
public function boot()
{

    UserModel::extend(function($model)
    {
        $model->addJsonable([
            'dogs',
        ]);
    });

    UsersController::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context){

        if (!$model instanceof UserModel) {
            return;
        }

        $form->addTabFields([
            'dogs' => [
                'label'      => 'My Dogs',
                'type'       => 'repeater',
                'form'       => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'breed' => [
                            'label' => 'Breed',
                            'type' => 'dropdown',
                            'options' => [
                                'labrador' => "Labrador",
                                'cocker'   => "Cocker Spaniel"
                            ]
                        ],
                        'name' => [
                            'label' => 'Name',
                            'type' => 'text',
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);

    });

}
```

Comment: That is what i am looking for.
Thanks