# how to define getName[field]Options() method in octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I got an error when trying to use

```
get*field*Options() method
```

to

```yaml
    field: name[field]
```

I tried to use:

```
getName[field]Options() method but it return an error.
```

How can I make this work?

fields.yaml

```yaml
    temakebum[tema]:                    
            tab: 'Kebaktian Umum & Komisi'             
            label: Tema
            oc.commentPosition: ''
            span: full
            type: text
    temakebum[bacaan]:
            label: 'Bahan Bacaan'
            oc.commentPosition: ''
            span: full
            type: dropdown
            tab: 'Kebaktian Umum & Komisi' 
    temakebum[pujian]:
            label: Pujian
            oc.commentPosition: ''
            span: full
            type: text
            tab: 'Kebaktian Umum & Komisi'
```

And in the models

```php
    public function getTemakebum[bacaan]Options() { 
      $bacaan = Db::table('mismaiti_mywarta_jadwlibdh')->where('group','umumraya')->pluck('bacaan','bacaan');
      return $bacaan;
    }
```

I need to put this several fields in as array into database table.. it is more like the repeater widget.. but the repeater require user to hit add new item button.. i don't want user to hit add new button but i want it there by default

if i use repeater getnamefieldOptions method is work well.. so if i use repeater the method is

```
getBacaanOptions(){ }
```

hope i said it clear enough..

Comment: What is the error ? Why don't you post code samples, example your fields.yaml file and the methods define in your model ? It's hard to help by just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is NOT** `getName[field]Options()` instead use `get[FieldName]Options()`

If your have a model `Car` and you have a field ( Column ) named `Manufacturer` then the method name is `getManufacturerOptions()`

The `fields.yaml` file of the Car Model should look like this;

```
  color:
      label: 'Color'  
      type: dropdown

  manufacturer:
      label: 'Manufacturer' 
      type: dropdown
```

then in Car mode add the method ;

```
public function getManufacturerOptions() {

    return [
        'volkswagen' => 'Volkswagen',
        'ford'       => 'Ford',
        'toyota'     => 'Toyota'
    ];

  // Or return ManufacturerModel::all()->pluck('name','id');
}

public function getColorOptions() {

    return [
        'black'    => 'Black', 
        'white'    => 'White'
    ];
}
```

Because the field type is dropdown the method should always return result as an array in the format : `Value => Label`

If there are no options return an empty array.

When you define the options in the `fields.yaml` then there's no need to add the method in your model

```
  color:
      label: 'Color' 
      type: dropdown
      options:
          black: Black
          white: White
```

**UPDATE**

1.Add a json column to your DB table `$table->json('temakebum')->nullable();`

2.Add `protected $jsonable = [ 'temakebum ']` in your Model Definition

3.Using the naming convention I mentioned above add `getBacaanOptions()` method to your model

4.Keep your fields.yaml file fields as they are, now the workaround is to change the field type from dropdown to partial for the `temakebum[bacaan]` field and populate the options there

5.Create a partial in your controller Directory and check the path matches the one in the `fields.yaml` file

So far `fields.yaml` looks like this

```
  temakebum[tema]:
          label: Tema 
          type: text
  temakebum[bacaan]:
          label: 'Bahan Bacaan' 
          type: partial
          path: $/authorName/pluginName/controllers/pluginControllerName/bacaan.htm
  temakebum[pujian]:
          label: Pujian 
          type: text
```

And your `bacaan.htm` partial like this :

```
<?php
$fieldOptions = $model->getBacaanOptions(); // See here we are fetching values
$Temakebum = json_decode($model->attributes['temakebum'], true)  ?: [];
?>
<select class="form-control custom-select" name="YourModelHere[temakebum][bacaan]">
    <?php foreach( $fieldOptions as $key=>$label) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $key ?>" <?php echo ( $Temakebum['bacaan'] == $key) ? "selected" : '';  ?> ><?= $label ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

( make sure to set the proper select name in the partial YourModelHere[temakebum][bacaan] )

Comment: My yaml file

    event[type]:
              label: Type
              type: dropdown

And in the models
  
    public function getEvent[type]Options(){
   -- retrieve data from database --

}

Comment: i want to make array of 12 fields.. so i just need to save in one field in database

Comment: is temakebum the model or column name where you want to store your array?

Comment: out of context.. is it possible for repeater field display automatic without user action to hit add new button?

Comment: @IsralBustami check new updated answer - Hope it helps. On my end it works fine

Comment: Raja i dont know that it can work this way.. so by using partial we can custom fields as how we want it to be..

Comment: @IsralBustami I think the best way to handle arrays is using the repeater widget, it's easier but I chose the partial because in your field.yaml you had field[arrayKey] and the method was throwing an issue, so the workaround is to populate data in the partial to avoid this problem. I am curious to know if there's a better way.

Comment: I used repeater but it is require user action to display the repeater.. if there is a way to do autoload for repeater so it automatically display a number set of form.. i would prefer use repeater..

Answer (score 1):

@Raja Khoury - thanks for making him understand how dropdown works ...

we can use this method for normal fields like `manufacturer`, but for complex fields we need to use different approach

We need to define this `methods` in **respective model:**

> First for `normal fields` there is simple approach **get[fieldname]Options**

```
public function get[fieldname]Options($value, $formData)
{
    return ['all' => 'All', ...];
}
```

> Second `specific method name` approach

`fields.yaml`

```
status:
    label: Blog Post Status
    type: dropdown
    options: listBacaan
```

`inside your model`

```
public function listBacaan($fieldName, $value, $formData)
{
    return ['key1' => 'data1', ...];
}
```

> Third **General** Approach

`inside your model`

```
public function getDropdownOptions($fieldName, $value, $formData)
{
    if ($fieldName == 'temakebum[bacaan]') {
        return ['all' => 'All', ...];
    }
    else {
        return ['' => '-- none --'];
    }
}
```

and for making field as **JSON** and storing it as an **array** inside single column **@Raja Khoury** already answered it in different question you can take **reference** from there: [Octobercms: How can I make a repeater field jsonable because I am creating this repeater field into a different plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550277/octobercms-how-can-i-make-a-repeater-field-jsonable-because-i-am-creating-this)

And if it work for you please up-vote his answer as well :)

Comment: this was a tough one :)

Comment: hmmm, yes sometime we confuse what the hack is this fieldname[someother][someother] make it really hard to use somewhere else :)

Comment: Woow.. thats how it work.. i have been trying to find solution from google.. i really appreciate hardik

Comment: @HardikSatasiya can i use the third approach for multi dropdown field.. so i don't need to define each dropdown with one function.. for instance i have 4 dropdown field with the third approach i just need to define the if condition refer to each dropdown.. isn't it?

Comment: yes why not it will the best case, use `switch... case` and you are good to go :)